# SQL Server query fast in first run, then extremely slow with other production data

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, inner-join, database-performance

I have a query which takes minutes to return.  It's fine once it's loaded into RAM, but the general performance is terrible when I change the parameters beyond what is in the cache.  There are approximately 1m rows in `thing` and 200k rows in `location`.  Both tables have indexes and keys.  Apart, the two queries (from thing and locations) return in <1 second, but when I do the join (which is on a FK) it takes upwards of a minute.

Query:

```
SELECT tip.id
    ,tip.NAME
    ,tip.location
    ,tip.time_start
    ,tip.time_end
    ,tip.is_meetup
    ,tip.utc_offset
    ,tip.type
    ,locations.NAME AS location_name
    ,locations.lat
    ,locations.long
FROM locations
INNER JOIN thing ON locations.id = thing.location
WHERE latitude BETWEEN 37.631281363768117
        AND 37.921136436231883
    AND longitude BETWEEN - 122.60055304642543
        AND - 122.23383795357458
    AND startTime BETWEEN 1373869967
        AND 1389869967
```

Execution Plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.3393.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="268.558" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="2.04298" StatementText="SELECT t.id, t.name, t.location, t.time_start, t.time_end, t.is_meetup, t.utc_offset, t.type,&#xD;&#xA;locations.name AS location_name,&#xD;&#xA;locations.latitude AS latitude, locations.longitude AS longitude&#xD;&#xA;FROM locations &#xD;&#xA;INNER JOIN Thing AS t&#xD;&#xA;ON locations.id = t.location &#xD;&#xA;WHERE latitude BETWEEN 32.631281363768117 AND 33.921136436231883&#xD;&#xA;AND longitude BETWEEN -118.60055304642543 AND -116.23383795357458&#xD;&#xA;AND time_start BETWEEN 1390869967 AND 1391869967&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x545542B8298CBC85" QueryPlanHash="0xA2BF90229E96DA92" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="40" CompileTime="11" CompileCPU="11" CompileMemory="464">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="524288" EstimatedPagesCached="131072" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4342" EstimateCPU="0.00243192" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="268.558" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.04298">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="name" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="latitude" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="id" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="name" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="location" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_start" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_end" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="is_meetup" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="utc_offset" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="type" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="12" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <NestedLoops Optimized="false" WithUnorderedPrefetch="true">
                <OuterReferences>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="id" />
                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                </OuterReferences>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="4059" EstimateCPU="0.016229" EstimateIO="0.10831" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="581.799" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.124539" TableCardinality="255461">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="name" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="latitude" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="id" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="5487" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="name" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="latitude" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="id" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Index="[IX_locations]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                    <SeekPredicates>
                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                        <SeekKeys>
                          <StartRange ScanType="GE">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="latitude" />
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(3.263128136376812e+001)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(3.263128136376812e+001)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(-1.186005530464255e+002)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(-1.186005530464255e+002)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </StartRange>
                          <EndRange ScanType="LE">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="latitude" />
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(3.392113643623188e+001)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(3.392113643623188e+001)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(-1.162338379535746e+002)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(-1.162338379535746e+002)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </EndRange>
                        </SeekKeys>
                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                    </SeekPredicates>
                    <Predicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ThingDB].[dbo].[locations].[longitude]&gt;=(-1.186005530464255e+002) AND [ThingDB].[dbo].[locations].[longitude]&lt;=(-1.162338379535746e+002)">
                        <Logical Operation="AND">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="GE">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="(-1.186005530464255e+002)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="LE">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="longitude" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Const ConstValue="(-1.162338379535746e+002)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Predicate>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="299" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="580.799" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.90315" TableCardinality="767469">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="id" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="name" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="location" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_start" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_end" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="is_meetup" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="utc_offset" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="type" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="12" ActualEndOfScans="5487" ActualExecutions="5487" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="id" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="name" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="location" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_start" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_end" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="is_meetup" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="utc_offset" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="type" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Index="[IX_Thing]" Alias="[t]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                    <SeekPredicates>
                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                        <SeekKeys>
                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="location" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[ThingDB].[dbo].[locations].[id]">
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[locations]" Column="id" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </Prefix>
                          <StartRange ScanType="GE">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_start" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1390869967)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(1390869967)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </StartRange>
                          <EndRange ScanType="LE">
                            <RangeColumns>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[ThingDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Thing]" Alias="[t]" Column="time_start" />
                            </RangeColumns>
                            <RangeExpressions>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1391869967)">
                                <Const ConstValue="(1391869967)" />
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </RangeExpressions>
                          </EndRange>
                        </SeekKeys>
                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                    </SeekPredicates>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
              </NestedLoops>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show us the execution plan XML? What is the dfinition of `thing` table?

Comment: @dean - I added it to my question.

Comment: Please provide info about indexes you have on both tables (IX_Locations, IX_Things, etc)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is about tenfold difference between actual and estimated number of rows coming from Index Seek operator on IX_locations index. It could be that the stats are stale, or that the distribution of data is skewed. But it's just part of the problem.

It would be interesting to know a bit more about Thing table. Taking into account that when you query Things table separately, filtering on startTime column, it returns in sub-second, my guess is that startTime is much more selective and also that this query uses some index on startTime column.

Try selecting from Things into a #temp table and join this to Locations.

Also, select from Locations into #temp table and join Things. Check the execution plan, what's the operator on Things table? If it's seek again, then my recommendation is to select from both Things and Locations into #temp tables first and then join them.

Comment: So, selecting the locations into a temp table, then joining that to thing worked perfectly.  It's back to the great speed I had with my separate queries.  Could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: It fixed the cardinality estimates. Optimizer doesn't have to guess about the number of rows from Locations, there is now exact number of rows in the temp.

Comment: Is there a general rule about when to go to a temp table?  I always just used them when I am reusing the same data over and over.  I didn't know there could be a 100x penalty for not using a temp table!

Comment: It's worth trying when estimates are off and rebuilding statistics doesn't help, and also in case when there's a complicated filter condition which can't be estimated properly. If the whole query is complicated (large number of tables joined) it's beneficial to divide it into parts, again using temp tables to store intermediates.

Comment: 1+ agreed 
temp table usually good when dealing with cardinality issue(divide and rule works most of the time). but bear in mind when you are processing huge data and estimations are way off from actual its better to use filtered statistics or filtered index.